# Run Microsoft Office apps in guest VM from host with VirtualBox

Tags: linux, bash, virtualbox, powershell, microsoft-office

#### Main goal

I'm using VirtualBox to use Microsoft Office apps in a Windows 10 virtual machine. My host OS is Ubuntu 23.04. I've made a few scripts that allows to launch Microsoft Office apps from the host. Specifically, it allows to open a Microsoft Office (.docx, .xlsx, etc) directly from the Linux file manager with double click. It worked very nicely until I upgraded Ubuntu and reinstalled a few packages recently.

#### Problem

It is possible to run an app in the guest from the host using the `VBoxManage guestcontrol` command. For example, the following command executed in the Terminal of the Ubuntu host opens Calculator in the Windows 10 guest.

```
VBoxManage guestcontrol $MY_VM_NAME run --exe "C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe" --username $MY_USERNAME --password $MY_PASSWORD
```

This works correctly. However, if I try to open a Microsoft Office app, as with the following command, it doesn't work. Nothing happens on the guest and the command execution never ends in the host Terminal.

```
VBoxManage guestcontrol $MY_VM_NAME run --exe "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\WINWORD.EXE" --username $MY_USERNAME --password $MY_PASSWORD
```

#### Full scripts

I created a "Word desktop app" in Ubuntu that executes the command `/my_path/runWord %F`. Below is the *runWord* script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# -- CODE DEVELOPERS/CONTRIBUTORS -- andpy73, sbnwl, 3Pilif, TVG
# https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=91799&start=15

clear

MY_VM_NAME="" # your VM name
MY_USERNAME="" # your Windows username
MY_PASSWORD="" # your Windows password

# If VM is not running 
if !( vboxmanage showvminfo "$MY_VM_NAME" | grep -c "running (since" ); then
    # Start the VM
    vboxmanage startvm "$MY_VM_NAME" --type separate > /dev/null
    # Sleep long enough so the VM is running before opening the app
    sleep 30 # (change the number of seconds depending how fast is the loading)
fi

# Create a temporary executable file in which we will write a VBoxManage command with Windows path as argument
if [ ! -d ~/.tmp ]; then
  mkdir ~/.tmp
fi
cd ~/.tmp
touch tmpfile
chmod +x tmpfile

# If a file is specified (double click on a Word file)
if [ -f "$1" ]; then
    # Write in the temporary executable file the VBoxManage command (change MY_USERNAME and MY_PASSWORD by your Windows username and password)...
    printf 'VBoxManage guestcontrol "'"$MY_VM_NAME"'" run --exe "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\WINWORD.EXE" --username '$MY_USERNAME' --password '$MY_PASSWORD' ' >> tmpfile
    # ...with the file as argument
    FILE=$(echo $1 | awk -F '/MOUNTED_PATH/' '{print $2}' | sed 's/\//\\/g') # file with Windows path (slash replace) from "/MOUNTED_PATH/" (change MOUNTED_PATH by the path of your shared folder in the VM)
    echo ' -- WINWORD/arg0 "'Z:\\$FILE'"' >> tmpfile # (change "Z:\\" with the your shared folder mounted drive in the VM)
else # else open blank file if no one opened or focus on the opened one (this is done by runWord.exe application in the VM)
    printf 'VBoxManage guestcontrol "'"$MY_VM_NAME"'" run --exe "C:\\APP_PATH\\runWord.exe" --username '$MY_USERNAME' --password '$MY_PASSWORD' ' >> tmpfile # (change APP_PATH by the path of the runWord.exe application in the VM)
fi

# Show the contents of tmpfile (only for debugging purpose)
echo '-------------------------------------------------------------------------'
echo 'This is the content of tmpfile for debugging purpose:'
echo ' '
cat tmpfile
echo ' '
echo '-------------------------------------------------------------------------'

# # Run the command in tmpfile
./tmpfile &
rm tmpfile

# Focus on the VM window
window_id=$(wmctrl -l | grep "$MY_VM_NAME" | awk '{print $1;}' | head -1) # Get window id
wmctrl -ia $window_id # Un-mininized the window (i.e. focus on it)
```

This script call an executable file (runWord.exe) in the Windows VM. I wrote a PowerShell (runWord.ps1) script and then converted it to a Windows executable file (runWord.exe) with the software "PS1 To Exe". I mainly copied the code from here: https://powershell.one/powershell-internals/extending-powershell/vbscript-and-csharp#c-to-the-rescue. Here is the file runWord.ps1:

```
$code = @'
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace API
{

    public class FocusWindow
    {
        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool AttachThreadInput(IntPtr idAttach, IntPtr idAttachTo, bool fAttach);


        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr lpdwProcessId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

        [DllImport("user32")]
        private static extern int BringWindowToTop(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(uint uiAction, uint uiParam, IntPtr pvParam, uint fWinIni);

        private const uint SPI_GETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT = 0x2000;
        private const uint SPI_SETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT = 0x2001;
        private const int SPIF_SENDCHANGE = 0x2;

        private const int SW_HIDE = 0;
        private const int SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1;
        private const int SW_NORMAL = 1;
        private const int SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2;
        private const int SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3;
        private const int SW_MAXIMIZE = 3;
        private const int SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE = 4;
        private const int SW_SHOW = 5;
        private const int SW_MINIMIZE = 6;
        private const int SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE = 7;
        private const int SW_SHOWNA = 8;
        private const int SW_RESTORE = 9;
        private const int SW_SHOWDEFAULT = 10;
        private const int SW_MAX = 10;

        public static void Focus(IntPtr windowHandle)
        {
            IntPtr blockingThread = GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(), IntPtr.Zero);
            IntPtr ownThread = GetWindowThreadProcessId(windowHandle, IntPtr.Zero);

            if (blockingThread == ownThread || blockingThread == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                SetForegroundWindow(windowHandle);
                ShowWindow(windowHandle, SW_NORMAL);
            }
            else
            {
                if (AttachThreadInput(ownThread, blockingThread, true))
                {
                    BringWindowToTop(windowHandle);
                    SetForegroundWindow(windowHandle);
                    ShowWindow(windowHandle, SW_NORMAL);
                    AttachThreadInput(ownThread, blockingThread, false);
                }
            }

            if (GetForegroundWindow() != windowHandle)
            {
                IntPtr Timeout = IntPtr.Zero;
                SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT, 0, Timeout, 0);
                SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT, 0, IntPtr.Zero, SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
                BringWindowToTop(windowHandle);
                SetForegroundWindow(windowHandle);
                ShowWindow(windowHandle, SW_NORMAL);
                SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT, 0, Timeout, SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
            }
        }
    }
}
'@

# Remove -PassThru in production. It is used only to expose the added types
Add-Type -PassThru -TypeDefinition $code

# Get the main window handle for the process you want to switch to the foreground
# in this example, the first instance of WINWORD is used
$process = Get-Process -Name WINWORD -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
    Select-Object -First 1

$mainWindowHandle = $process.MainWindowHandle

# If process exists
if ($process)
{
    # Focus application window
    [API.FocusWindow]::Focus($mainWindowHandle)
}else{
    # Open application
    Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\WINWORD.EXE" 
}
```

Please let me know if you see how to solve the specific problem I've pointed out or if you think of a better way to reach the main goal.

Comment: That feature is called Unity in VMware and only works in Windows machines (guest and host). So if the Ubuntu updates have stopped VBOX from issuing guest commands, it may no longer be possible.

Comment: I'm not sure how much the Ubuntu upgrade is responsible for the problem. Guest commands work fine with opening Calculator for example. I don't know why it doesn't work for Microsoft Office app executables. Since the command line execution does not return any error, it is hard to know what's happening.

Comment: Is there any reason to use MS Office suite, rather than free LibreOffice, which runs natively in Linux, and which can handle pretty much all Office documents, including older doc versions that are no longer supported by Office? Is this a corporate requirement?

Comment: Yes, I do have my reasons. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

The issue comes from **VirtualBox Guest Additions v7**. Downgraded to a v6 version solve the problem.

### Details

- Host OS: Ubuntu 23.10
- Guest OS: Windows 10
- VirtualBox: v7.0.10

1. In the Windows 10 VM, uninstall *Oracle VM VirtualBox Guest Additions* (Control Panel > Uninstall a program).
2. Power off the VM.
3. Download the ISO file from an older version of the VirtualBox Guest Additions [here](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/). Works with `VBoxGuestAdditions_6.1.48.iso`.
4. (Optional) Save the ISO file under `~/.config/VirtualBox/`.
5. In the VirtualBox Manager, choose the ISO file for **SATA Port 1: [Optical Drive] VBoxGuestAdditions_6.1.48.iso**.
6. Start the VM.
7. Under "This PC", double click on **CD Drive (D:) VirtualBox Guest Additions**, then on `VBoxWindowsAdditions.exe` and follow the instructions to install VirtualBox Guest Additions v6.1.48.

### Note

None of the VirtualBox Guest Additions v7 seems to work. Then, since only the VirtualBox Guest Additions v6 are working, it is maybe better to also use VirtualBox v6 instead of VirtualBox v7.